# Change orientation of ios keyboard?

Tags: cordova, facebook-graph-api, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, facebook-invite-friends

Im using phonegap.build and i need to do the following on my game app:

The game is forced to landscaped mode at all time, and it has no canvas version of it, this is ios and android only game, and i use it with phonegap.

With the facebook-connect plugin:

```
https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin
```

I have a dialog, which i open with facebook-connect api:

facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog(Object options, Function success, Function failure)

in the options i have:

```
{
    method: "apprequests",
    message: "Come on man, check out my application."
}
```

which results in this:

[image]

I have a problem with that window, it opens in portrait mode, and i have an landscape only app ( it means the user, when prompt to this screen, should change the orientation, which is a bad behaviour )

I searched for hours for a solution for this and no luck.

Now, if i'm letting it stay like this, and i press on the 'search more friends' input, the keyboard opens on landscape mode, which results in this awkward behavior:

[image]

My question are those:

1) Is there any way to fix the popup of facebook to be landscape?

2) If no to 1, is it possible to control the keyboard as to how it opens (landscape or portrait), with any configuration in the config.xml (this is phonegap build) or any plugin that do such a thing

3) If no to all, what are my options to invite friends to my app (invitable is not an option, this is no canvas app)

Thank you

Comment: Hmm than can be a complicated issue to manage. What is the value of `<preference name="Orientation" value="" />` in your `config.xml` ? Also, does it behave the same way with orientation locked and unlocked (iOS setting) ?

Comment: This is not Facebook developers who are responsible of that since it has been fixed there : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-3.x (3.18 : Fixed the orientation of web dialogs when linking against the iOS 8 SDK).

Comment: Did you try both on your phone and your emulator ?

Comment: Just to answer your question, just having the `<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />` is enough to make FB SDK adapt to the app orientation. On Android it does work perfectly.

Comment: Help! anyone? something? anything? those preferences not working at all

Comment: open an issue on the plugins git page or try another one

Answer (score 1):

@totothegreat,
On #1 I don't know.
On #2, this is possible on Andrdoid. I don't know iOS.
on #3, I don't know much about facebook stuff.

For Android, you need to set the orientation to landscape, and you need to tell Android you will handle the orientation and you will handle the redraw (which you will never need to do). This means you have control of the keyboard as well. In this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/phonegap/ben$20jones/phonegap/UdXbU8a-UKk/SAZg9F3YyzoJ), Ben Jones creates a slightly different solution.

Below are the two XML attibutes (android:configChanges & android:screenOrientation) you need to add to the `<activity>` element of the *AndroidManifest.xml*, **BUT you can exchange both attributes for their equivalents in *config.xml***

```
     <activity android:name="basicScreenSize" android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|locale"
                    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

The documentation you are looking for is buried in the [`<activity>` section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) of the documentation. Again, the attributes you want are [android:configChanges](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) and [android:screenOrientation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen).

Lastly, if you want to implement this with *config.xml*, then I suggest you [read the thread with Ben Jones' implementation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/phonegap/ben$20jones/phonegap/UdXbU8a-UKk/SAZg9F3YyzoJ). Best of luck, text me back, if you are still having problems.

Comment: Im sorry but the question was only for ios... so your answer is just not relevant....

Comment: FYI: If this helps. There is currently no way to ask for a splashscreen with iOS that is in landscape mode. I don't know iOS that well, but I can image there is a solution, but it must come from the native side of iOS. You can read my [NOTES](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-Splashscreen-Test/blob/master/NOTES) on this. BUGS -> DATE: 2015-06-07   BTW, you likely want to modify your original post to say it is for iOS only. The post implies you need both answers. Best of Luck

Answer (score 0):

@totothegreat, on this subject - part of the reason I am helping is because I will need to solve this problem myself. Here is what I have. To make this change on iOS you'll need to write an Info.plist (or equivalent) - which is an XML file. This Info.plist is equivalent to AndroidManifest.xml and config.xml

**Google**: [apple ios Info.plist keyboard landscape](https://www.google.com/search?q=apple+ios+Info.plist+keyboard+landscape)

So far I have:

1. [About Information Property List
   Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html)
2. [UIInterfaceOrientation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW13)
3. [UISupportedInterfaceOrientations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW10)

Accordingly, you can integrate these *attributes* in Phonegap's config.xml. One phonegap, start with

[Config File Elements](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_config_file_element.md.html#Config%20File%20Elements)

The instructions to write those *attribute* additions into config.xml are here:

[config-file Element](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification_config_file_element)

**Please note**, the documentation in *Config File Element* says that adding to the config.xml is similar in format to plug-ins, and the *config-file Element* example is from the plug-ins.

Let me know how it goes. I'll need to try this myself.
Jesse

Comment: @totothegreat, I have it working now, with standard Phonegap Build. Note, they just upgrade two (2) days ago. [screenshot of layout](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jessemonroy650/mobileui-popup/master/IMG_0020.png)